# Trigger a function in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, triggers, simplepie

I'm trying to build an "intelligent" RSS-Reader by using CakePHP + SimplePie.
In my admin section, when I add a link, my function save the link to the DB and then extract all links from the rss feed and then store them in the DB.
My problem now, is that I want to execute that action every once in while to populate the DB with new links.

Is it possible to do it with CakePHP..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a [shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html) and use a cronjob to execute it at the interval you need.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will check it out ASAP. Besides cronjob, is there any other internal[in CakePHP] solution..??